# Inductive or capacitive load?

Tags: capacitive, inductive, lcr, self-resonant-frequency

Here I have a series LCR circuit with resonant frequency greater than 200Hz. Is there a way to know whether this circuit is an inductive or a capacitive load?

Edit: The only additional information we have is the phase shift between the inductor (with resistance r) and the resistor which is +45 degrees.

Here is the schematic:

[image]

Below are plotted voltages of the inductor (plot b) and the resistor (plot a.). The X-axis refers to the time with scale π/4  by division and Y-axis represents the voltage with scale 1V by division.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please embed a schematic.

Comment: Label your axes! What are the two different curves supposed to be?

Comment: @Hilmar As mentioned the curve b refers to the inductor voltage and curve b refers to the resistor voltage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to know whether this circuit is an inductive or a capacitive load?

Yes. The circuit will have inductive reactance when the driving frequency is above the resonant frequency, and it will have capacitative reactance when the driving frequency is below the resonant frequency.

Comment: +1 for answering the actual question asked :)

Comment: I get it .Thanks for answering.